# How to determine if a function is one-one using derivatives?

Tags: functions, derivatives, slope

Generally, the method used is - for the function, $f$, to be one-one we prove that for all $x, y$ within domain of the function, $f$, $f(x)=f(y)$ implies that $x=y$.

Another method is by using calculus.

If $f '(x)>0$ or $f '(x)<0$ for all $x$ in domain of the function, then  the function is one-one. But if $f '(x)=0$ at some points (let the set of such points be $A$) then at those points we check $f ''(x)$. If $f ''(x)$ is not equal to zero at all points in set $A$, then the function is not one-one. If $f ''(x)=0$ at some set, $B$ of points (set $B$ is a subset of set $A$) , then we check $f '''(x)$ at all points in set $B$. If $f '''(x)$ is not equal to zero at all those points in set $B$ then the function is one-one.

My problem here is -

1. Is the above method (using calculus) correct to the extent that I have written it? If it is correct, then please complete it (since I have not considered what happens if $f '''(x)=0$ ). If it is incorrect, please give the reasons as to why it is incorrect and provide (if there exists) another method to prove that the function is one-one (apart from the methods mentioned above).
2. Do we have to continue going like this for eternity? Checking $f ''''(x)$, then $f '''''(x)$, then $f ''''''(x)$......(you get the idea) if they successively come out to be zero? Or do we just prove that every derivative after a certain derivative is 0, and leave it at that?
3. While writing the method, I have written it, keeping only functions having both domain and range as subsets of real numbers, in mind. In case the method for other kinds of functions is different (which, in my opinion, should not be the case), please elaborate on that front too.

Please try and use examples where possible

Comment: Your "calculus" method amounts to find out whether $f(x)$ is strictly monotonic. This can be checked regardless of differentiability.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f: (0,1) \cup  (2,3) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \in (0,1)  \\ x-2 & , x \in(2,3)\end{cases}$$

The function is not injective as $f(\frac12)=f(\frac52).$

I don't think derivative alone is sufficient to conclude that it is injective.

Comment: Hmm... I see. What if we restrict ourselves to continuous and differentiable functions?

Comment: This function is continuous and differentiable right?

Comment: I think you might be referring to functions with connected domain.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The function you have given is continuous. And yes again, I was talking of functions with connected domain (if it means that there are no 'breaks' in the graph of the function, if I may say so).

Comment: And seeing as the 'calculus' method I have given is not applicable for all functions - could you also mention the set (or kind) of functions over which the method is applicable? I think - continuous, differentiable, connected domain - should pretty much cover it. Though, I've been wrong before. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a proof yet so I'm not able to comment about the correctness.